# Recursive filtering of array of objects without child nodes

Tags: javascript, recursion, filtering

I want to filter an array of objects, recursively based on an input array that filters the values and filters out "empty nodes".

This is an example:

```
const nodes = [{
  value: 'World',
  children: [{
    value: 'Europe',
    children: [{
      value: 'BeNeLux',
      children: [{
        value: 'NL'
      }, {
        value: 'DE'
      }, {
        value: 'LU'
      }]
    }, {
      value: 'AL'
    }, {
      value: 'ZW'
    }, {
      value: 'UK' // lol
    }]
  }]
}]
```

In the array above, nodes have: `value` and optionally `children`.

I want a function, that I feed an input array that should filter the values + children of the `nodes` array as listed above so:

```
const valuesToBeRemoved = ['NL', 'DE', 'LU', 'ZW', 'UK']
```

The expected output should then be:

```
const expectedNodesOutput = [{
  value: 'World',
  children: [{
    value: 'Europe',
    children: [{
      value: 'AL'
    }]
  }]
}]
```

This is what I have tried but it is not working correctly because it's not correctly recursive, and it should filter out nodes that are empty (also curious on how other people come up with a solution that might be cleaner):

```
const filterNodes = (filter, node) => {
  if (node.children) {
    const children = node.children
      .map(child => filterNodes(filter, child))
      .filter(x => x)

    if (children.length) {
      return {
        ...node,
        children
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (!filter.includes(node.value)) {
      return node
    }
  }
}

const getFilteredNodes = (filter, nodes) => {
  return filterNodes(filter, { children: nodes })?.children || []
}
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KOXBLe

Comment: @alfasin not sure about that, the code isn't working as intended

Comment: @alfasin no it's not. Code Review requires that the existing code works as intended. It is explicitly stated in the question that the existing code does not.

Comment: Then clarify your question, right now you ask "if there would be a cleaner / more efficient way" which implies this code works.

Comment: @alfasin no clarification needed. You just didn't read `but is not working correctly because it's not correctly recursive and it should filter out nodes that are empty`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that statement is not clear as well.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I honestly don't think this question should be upvoted until it gets cleaned up...

Comment: OP should add some unit tests

Comment: @dfhwze that's always true, but totally unrelated to the question.

Comment: It could have prevented all comments we have so far :)

Comment: @dfhwze it could have prevented half of the questions on this website LoL :)

Comment: @dfhwze yep hehe

Comment: @alfasin You are right, clean up the question sorry about that. So I have to get it working, PLUS I am curious how people solve the question to see if there are better "magical" es6 ways

Comment: Are you okay with mutating the input or do you need a new object?

Comment: sounds dangerous.

Comment: @adiga immutable pl0x

Comment: you got a tree w no nodes? im lost. are we filtering a array of objects based on whether the object contains a specific property value?

Comment: FYI Germany (DE) is not part of the Benelux. You most likely meant Belgium (BE) instead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` does not respect nested properties and otjherwise, you need to mutate the given data structure.

Instead, you could reduce the node structure by looking at the children and if an not empty array is returned, take the actual value as well.

```js
function filter(array, remove) {
    return array.reduce((r, { value, children }) => {
        if (remove.includes(value)) return r;
        if (!children) {
            r.push({ value });
            return r;
        }
        children = filter(children, remove);
        if (children.length) r.push({ value, children });
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var nodes = [{ value: 'World', children: [{ value: 'Europe', children: [{ value: 'BeNeLux', children: [{ value: 'NL' }, { value: 'DE' }, { value: 'LU' }] }, { value: 'AL' }, { value: 'ZW' }, { value: 'UK' }] }] }],
    remove = ['NL', 'DE', 'LU', 'ZW', 'UK'],
    result = filter(nodes, remove);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an immutable way to remove values and prune the empty arrays from the recursive structure. They need to be performed separately in order for pruning to respect the modifications caused by removed values:

```js
function remove (nodes, values) {
  return nodes.map(
    ({ value, children }) => children
      ? { value, children: remove(children, values) }
      : { value }
  ).filter(
    ({ value }) => !values.includes(value)
  );
}

function prune (nodes) {
  return nodes.map(
    ({ value, children }) => children
      ? { value, children: prune(children) }
      : { value }
  ).filter(
    ({ children }) => !children || children.length > 0
  );
}

const nodes = [{
  value: 'World',
  children: [{
    value: 'Europe',
    children: [{
      value: 'BeNeLux',
      children: [{
        value: 'NL'
      }, {
        value: 'DE'
      }, {
        value: 'LU'
      }]
    }, {
      value: 'AL'
    }, {
      value: 'ZW'
    }, {
      value: 'UK'
    }]
  }]
}];

const valuesToBeRemoved = ['NL', 'DE', 'LU', 'ZW', 'UK'];

console.log(prune(remove(nodes, valuesToBeRemoved)));
```

You can even make the code more DRY by using a higher order function to define `remove()` and `prune()`:

```js
const recurseBy = key => filter => function callback (nodes, ...args) {
  return nodes.map(
    ({ [key]: nodes, ...rest }) => nodes
      ? { ...rest, [key]: callback(nodes, ...args) }
      : { ...rest }
  ).filter(
    item => filter(item, ...args)
  );
};

const filterBy = recurseBy('children');
const remove = filterBy(({ value }, values) => !values.includes(value));
const prune = filterBy(({ children }) => !children || children.length > 0);

const nodes = [{
  value: 'World',
  children: [{
    value: 'Europe',
    children: [{
      value: 'BeNeLux',
      children: [{
        value: 'NL'
      }, {
        value: 'DE'
      }, {
        value: 'LU'
      }]
    }, {
      value: 'AL'
    }, {
      value: 'ZW'
    }, {
      value: 'UK'
    }]
  }]
}];

const valuesToBeRemoved = ['NL', 'DE', 'LU', 'ZW', 'UK'];

console.log(prune(remove(nodes, valuesToBeRemoved)));
```

I noticed in the question you used optional chaining syntax. If your project allows ESnext (aka TC39 proposals), you can use the pipeline operator and partial application syntax to clean up the calls.

```
console.log(prune(remove(nodes, valuesToBeRemoved)));
```

is equivalent to

```
nodes
  |> remove(?, valuesToBeRemoved)
  |> prune(?)
  |> console.log(?)
```